# What is the critical bug in ETL testing and how can we find it?

Tags: testing, etl, data-warehouse

What is a critical bug in ETL testing and how can we find it?

Please explain me because I feel it is very important question for every interview.

Comment: Please specify your question more. There is no general answer on how to find bugs.

Comment: The Question is " What was the Critical bug you have found and raised a defect".

Comment: This is the testing. Use static or dynamic testing and find this bug.

Comment: This is a very open ended question. Please add context to your question..

Answer (score 0):

According to ISTQB, Software, in general, has two kind of risks:

1. Project Risk
2. Product Risk

Project Risks are all risks that may delay a project or fail a project.
Product Risks are all risks that occur to the user after the release (eg harm).

Software may have "Failures" which are bugs that occur during runtime.
The reason for a failure is a "Defect" in the code.
A Defect was eg made by a Developer while he/she was creating the code (Error).

Bug is more a general synonym for all three or a failure.
Critical bugs may lead to a "Risk".